# how to calculate CRC value for a file in C#.net?

Tags: c#, crc, visual-c++, crc32

i want to calculate the CRC value for a file using 32-bit algorithm in C#.net....

Answer (score 8):

```
Algorithm is straightforward (rewritten from c++)

class Crc32
{
    public static uint CountCrc(byte[] pBuf)
    {
        // Table of CRC-32's of all single byte values
        uint[] crctab = new uint[] {
          0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419,
          0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4,
          0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988, 0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07,
          0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2, 0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de,
          0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7, 0x136c9856,
          0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9,
          0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4,
          0xa2677172, 0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b,
          0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c, 0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3,
          0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59, 0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a,
          0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423, 0xcfba9599,
          0xb8bda50f, 0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
          0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d, 0x76dc4190,
          0x01db7106, 0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f,
          0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433, 0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e,
          0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d, 0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01,
          0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e, 0x6c0695ed,
          0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457, 0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950,
          0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3,
          0xfbd44c65, 0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2,
          0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7, 0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 0x4369e96a,
          0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0, 0x44042d73, 0x33031de5,
          0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9, 0x5005713c, 0x270241aa, 0xbe0b1010,
          0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
          0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17,
          0x2eb40d81, 0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad, 0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6,
          0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a, 0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615,
          0x73dc1683, 0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84, 0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8,
          0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1, 0xf00f9344,
          0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb,
          0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7, 0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a,
          0x67dd4acc, 0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5,
          0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e, 0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1,
          0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b, 0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c,
          0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55, 0x316e8eef,
          0x4669be79, 0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
          0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f, 0xc5ba3bbe,
          0xb2bd0b28, 0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31,
          0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d, 0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c,
          0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
          0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38, 0x92d28e9b,
          0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242,
          0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1,
          0x18b74777, 0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c,
          0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69, 0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45, 0xa00ae278,
          0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2, 0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7,
          0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db, 0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc, 0x40df0b66,
          0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
          0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605,
          0xcdd70693, 0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf, 0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8,
          0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94, 0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b,
          0x2d02ef8d
        };

        uint c = 0xffffffff;  // begin at shift register contents 
        int i, n = pBuf.Length;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            c = crctab[((int)c ^ pBuf[i]) & 0xff] ^ (c >> 8);
        }
        return c ^ 0xffffffff;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the shift register should begin with 0x04C11DB7 rather than 0xffffffff.

Comment: I prefer 0xffffffff to have it compatible with other software. For example, for the situation, there are no data the result is 0 which is for example chechsum of zero lenght file in TotalCommander

Comment: Why do you need that table of CRC values? Just curious

Answer (score 1):

I used [Crc32.NET](https://github.com/force-net/Crc32.NET/tree/develop/Crc32.NET) in BackgroundWorker:

```
private void Crc_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  FileInfo file = e.Argument as FileInfo;
  uint r = 0;
  using (var s = file.OpenRead())
  {
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int len = s.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
    r = Crc32Algorithm.Compute(buff, 0, len);
    while ((len = s.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) > 0)
      r = Crc32Algorithm.Append(r, buff, 0, len);
  }
  e.Result = Convert.ToString(r, 16).ToUpper();
}
```