# Equivalent to Unix cksum in Windows

Tags: c#, checksum, crc32

I download a file and his checksum (generated by cksum Unix command).

So, I want, in my C# app test if the Checksum is in adequation with the app I downloaded.

I checked at the Unix man page of chsum:

> ```
>   The cksum command calculates and prints to standard output a checksum
>   for each named file, the number of octets in the file and the
>   filename.
>
>   cksum uses a portable algorithm based on a 32-bit Cyclic Redundancy
>   Check.  This algorithm finds a broader spectrum of errors than the
>   16-bit algorithms used by sum (see sum(1)).  The CRC is the sum of the
>   following expressions, where x is each byte of the file.
>
>        x^32 + x^26 + x^23 +x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7
>        + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x^1 + x^0
>
>   The results of the calculation are truncated to a 32-bit value.  The
>   number of bytes in the file is also printed.
> ```

So i wrote a simple program that does the sum :

```
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(@"MyApp").ToArray();

int cksum = 0;

foreach (byte x in arr)
{
    cksum += (x ^ 32 + x ^ 26 + x ^ 23 + x ^ 22 + x ^ 16 + x ^ 12 + x ^ 11 + x ^ 10 + x ^ 8 + x ^ 7 + x ^ 5 + x ^ 4 + x ^ 2 + x ^ 1 + x ^ 0);
}
```

But checksums aren't the same, how can I fix this?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

1) The modified algorithm is:

```
uint cksum = 0;

foreach (byte b in arr)
{
    var x = (uint)b;

    cksum += (IntPow(x, 32)
        + IntPow(x, 26) + IntPow(x, 23) + IntPow(x, 22)
        + IntPow(x, 16) + IntPow(x, 12) + IntPow(x, 11) + IntPow(x, 10)
        + IntPow(x, 8) + IntPow(x, 7) + IntPow(x, 5) + IntPow(x, 4) + IntPow(x, 2) + IntPow(x, 1) + IntPow(x, 0));
}
```

2) I used the `class Crc32 : HashAlgorithm`

Given an Unix file where the Crc32 is : 2774111254

- 1) Gives me : 4243613712
- 2) Gives me : 3143134679 (with a seed of 0)

What I'm doing wrong !?

Comment: For a C# implementation of crc32 check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4656659/11343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# the `^` symbol is the exclusive-or operator. You want the function [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

This gives the piower of two floating point numbers, alteratives are suggested at [How do you do *integer* exponentiation in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383587/how-do-you-do-integer-exponentiation-in-c)

So, your code would look something like:

```
cksum += Math.pow(x,32) + Math.pow(x,26)
```

Be aware also of the last statement:

> The results of the calculation are truncated to a 32-bit value.  The
>   number of bytes in the file is also printed.

Is this signed (`int`) or unsigned (`uint`)

you could of course use the following:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35134/How-to-calculate-CRC-in-C

Comment: I tried the class provided by your link but haven't the same result. Unix : `>cksum file2.exe ` : 2774111254 ; `Crc32.Compute(arr);`: 1514701405 ; and previous code corrected with Pow : 4243613712. What are they different ?

Answer (score 2):

Those are powers, not xors. See [Wikipedia about CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_Redundancy_Check).

Answer (score 2):

In c# ^ is not a raise-to-the-power operator, but an xor operator, whereas the CRC is written using general mathsy terminology not specific to any language.

Don't use a standard "pow" function either since those will normally use floating point to represent very large numbers such as x^32.

Whereas what you want is to keep the *low* 32 bits of the answer. Probably the best way to is:

- Write your own integer-power function, which takes arguments as Ints and calculates x^N for you by doing multiplication of x N times, and trusting the .NET runtime to be reasonably efficient (or if it's too slow, using some optimisation like doing exponentiation by squaring). Don't let the numbers grow too big, either by rounding off after each multiple using the remainder or bitwise-and operators, or using unchecked values and trusting them to wrap round and keep the low 32 bits each time.
- Look for a library or existing code which calculates a CRC32 directly (eg. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+crc32)

Answer (score 2):

Also see this correct implementation https://cksum.codeplex.com/